# What do you call an ending that explains everything that happened prior to it?

Tags: terminology

In *Stein's Gate,* the viewers finally get to understand all of the weird things that happened at the beginning of the series at the end, or near the end of the series.

What do you call an ending or plot that features something like that?

Comment: Isn't that just called a conclusion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Perhaps a ‘Denouement’

From TV tropes, a [denouement](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Denouement) is:

> French for "unknotting", and **denotes the point in the story when mysteries are unraveled, fates are determined and explanations made**.